# Problems with basic Javascript front end code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner at javascript and jQuery. I'm working on essentially my first experiment with javascript. So far I've only written code so as to change the questions when I click on next or previous. This webpage is supposed to be a quiz and is supposed to dynamically change questions when a button is clicked. However It's not doing that because there is presumably something wrong with the javascript code. Can you help me correct that?

Javascript:

```
var allquestions = [{
    question: "Who was the First President of the United States?", 
    choices: ["George Washington", "Thomas Jefferson", "John Adams", "Barack Obama"],
    answer: 0,
}, {
    question: "Who sanctioned the Transcontinental Railway?",
    choices: ["Thomas Jefferson", "Andrew Jackson", "Abraham Lincoln", "Dwight Eisenhower"],
    answer: 2
},
{
    question: "Who is the only president to resign in American history?",
    choices:["Richard Nixon", "Gerald Ford", "Andrew Johnson", "George H W Bush"],
    answer: 0
}];

var display = function(i){
    $('h1').append(allquestions[i].question);
    $('#quiz').append(allquestions[i].choices[0]);
    $('input[name=Option b]').append(allquestions[i].choices[1]);
    $('input[name=Option c]').append(allquestions[i].choices[2]);
    $('input[name=Option d]').append(allquestions[i].choices[3]);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
var i = 0;
display(i);
$('button[name=next]').click(function(){
    ++i;
    display(i);
});

$('button[name=prev').click(function(){
    --i;
    display(i);
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Le Quiz on American History </h1>
   <div id = "quiz">
     <form id = "choices">
        <input type = "radio" name="Option a" value = "0"><br>
        <input type = "radio" name="Option b" value = "1"><br>
        <input type = "radio" name="Option c" value = "2"><br>
        <input type = "radio" name="Option d" value = "3">
     </form>
   </div>
   <div id = "buttons">
   <button type = "button" name = "submit">Submit</button> <br><br>
   <button type = "button" name = "prev">Previous</button>
   <button type = "button" name = "next">Next</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, how would you do it better? And how would you add functionality to the answers. Please feel free to play around with this. Thanks.

Comment: It's not very helpful to say "something is wrong, help me troubleshoot it". Have you check your browser console for error messages? Have you validated your JS?

Comment: I did. I got an error saying "Failed to execute query selector on Document." 

I'm not sure what that means. As I've said I'm just starting out.

Comment: Is the console giving you the line in your document where it apparently fails to select the DOM element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New JavaScript code For you which is working

```
var allquestions = [{
question: "Who was the First President of the United States?", 
choices: ["George Washington", "Thomas Jefferson", "John Adams", "Barack Obama"],
answer: 0,
}, {
question: "Who sanctioned the Transcontinental Railway?",
choices: ["Thomas Jefferson", "Andrew Jackson", "Abraham Lincoln", "Dwight Eisenhower"],
answer: 2
},
{
question: "Who is the only president to resign in American history?",
choices:["Richard Nixon", "Gerald Ford", "Andrew Johnson", "George H W Bush"],
answer: 0
}];

var display = function(i){
$('h1').html(allquestions[i].question);
$('#l1').html(allquestions[i].choices[0]);
$('#l2').html(allquestions[i].choices[1]);
$('#l3').html(allquestions[i].choices[2]);
$('#l4').html(allquestions[i].choices[3]);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
var i = 0;
display(i);
$('button[name=next]').click(function(){
++i;
display(i);
});

$('button[name=prev]').click(function(){
--i;
display(i);
});
});
```

Html Code for you

```
<body>
<h1> Le Quiz on American History </h1>
<div id = "quiz">
 <form id = "choices">
    <label for="a1" id="l1"></label><input id="a1" type = "radio" name="Option" value = "0"><br>
    <label for="a2" id="l2"></label><input id="a2" type = "radio" name="Option" value = "1"><br>
    <label for="a3" id="l3"></label><input id="a3"type = "radio" name="Option" value = "2"><br>
    <label for="a4" id="l4"></label><input id="a4" type = "radio" name="Option" value = "3">
 </form>
</div>
<div id = "buttons">
<button type = "button" name = "submit">Submit</button> <br><br>
<button type = "button" name = "prev">Previous</button>
<button type = "button" name = "next">Next</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Please add jquery file to your page as well.
If you have any Question feel free to ask about this  code because its tested on my system and working.

Comment: You should somehow highlight the difference or what was wrong with the original code in your answer.

Comment: Thanks next time I will try to do this at the time of posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your webpage got two problems:

Prob1. You missed to add JQuery script file.

sol: Add this line

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

above (important) the line

```
<script src='script.js'></script>
```

Prob2. Syntax error with radio element names.

sol: (basic) Remove spaces in radio element names and change the names in script also.

In script change these three lines:

```
$('input[name=Option b]').append(allquestions[i].choices[1]);
$('input[name=Option c]').append(allquestions[i].choices[2]);
$('input[name=Option d]').append(allquestions[i].choices[3]);
```

to

```
$('input[name=Option_b]').append(allquestions[i].choices[1]);
$('input[name=Option_c]').append(allquestions[i].choices[2]);
$('input[name=Option_d]').append(allquestions[i].choices[3]);`
```

and in html change

```
<input type = "radio" name="Option a" value = "0"><br>
    <input type = "radio" name="Option b" value = "1"><br>
    <input type = "radio" name="Option c" value = "2"><br>
    <input type = "radio" name="Option d" value = "3">
```

to

```
<input type = "radio" name="Option_a" value = "0"><br>
    <input type = "radio" name="Option_b" value = "1"><br>
    <input type = "radio" name="Option_c" value = "2"><br>
    <input type = "radio" name="Option_d" value = "3">
```